# How to set Oracle JDK support FIPS mode

Tags: java, ibm-mq, fips

Currently. I have to create client application to connect IBM MQ server which only support TLS. After google a lot. I know the JDK used have to support FIPS.

Any one can help with how to set it up on Linux server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right. FIPS is not supported as default in Oracle JDK.

1. Download JCE from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html
2. Put the extracted jars to %JAVA_HOME%/jre/lib/security. But these jars are just interface.
3. Install [NSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/NSS) as an FIPS implementation.
4. Change your java.security provider to it.

Or you can switch to use IBM SDK will is easy to config FIPS mode, Details please refer to IBM knowledge center.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of other resources that would be useful here.

- TLS support with MQ 8.0.0.2 JMS is available the Oracle JRE. [Blog article](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/messaging/entry/bitesize_blogging_mq_v8_fix_pack_8_0_0_2_mq_classes_now_support_tls_with_the_oracle_jre?lang=en)
- Also [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/FIPS.html?cm_mc_uid=56199597426613989502929&cm_mc_sid_50200000=1450450151) from Oracle's documentation (cited in the the above article) gives more information FIPS in Oralce JRS