# Is Java AES encryption FIPS 140-2 compliant?

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, aes

I have encryption module written in Java 8 as below-

```
private static final String SECRET_KEY_PASSPHRASE="012345678901234567890123456789012"; //256 bit

public Cipher getCipherInstance(int encryptionMode)
            throws ... /*throws necessary exceptions*/{


        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

        byte[] keyBytes=getKeyBytes(SECRET_KEY_PASSPHRASE);
/*getKeyBytes function returns 16 bytes from 256 bit passphrase*/

        SecretKeySpec secretKeySpecy = new SecretKeySpec(SECRET_KEY_PASSPHRASE.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");
        IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(keyBytes);

        cipher.init(encryptionMode, secretKeySpecy, ivParameterSpec);
        return cipher;
    }
```

I am encrypting/decrypting data using cipher object returned from above function.

Is my code or Java implementation of AES or Cipher class FIPS 140-2 compliant?

Comment: What version of Java? In earlier versions you needed the Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) for FIPS 140-2 - **or** BouncyCastle. See [also](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34348687/2970947)

Comment: Its java 8.I need to check minor version.

Comment: The library may by FIPS compliant, but your code has security drawbacks for sure (using key as IV, no integrity check, ...)

Comment: But I am not getting any document clearly saying that Java AES implementation is FIPS compliant.

Comment: Default Java JCE is imho not FIPS compliant as supporting weaker or obsolete primitives.  AES is a listed cryptographic function supported in FIPS-140-2 (Annex A). To ensure FIPS compliance you may use FIPS complaint JCE implementations (IBM FIPS JSSE, RSA BSAFE, BouncyCastle BC-FA, JSSE in FIPS mode  ...) effectively disabling weak and unsupported ciphers or compliant hardware (smartcard, hsm). FIPS-140-2 is about cryptographic modules, so it you cannot ask the Cipher class or your app to be compliant (regardless apparent weaknesses in the implementation)

Comment: I was about to answer, but everything is already in the comment above. @gusto2, could you turn that into an answer?

Answer (score 0):

> But I am not getting any document clearly saying that Java AES implementation is FIPS compliant.

Default Java JCE is IMHO not FIPS compliant as supporting weaker or obsolete primitives.

AES is a listed cryptographic function supported in FIPS-140-2 (Annex A).

To ensure FIPS compliance you may use FIPS compliant JCE implementations (IBM FIPS JSSE, RSA BSAFE, BouncyCastle BC-FA, ..) or JSSE in FIPS mode (connected to FIPS compliant hardware - smartcard, hsm).

> Is my code or Java implementation of AES or Cipher class FIPS 140-2 compliant?

FIPS-140-2 is about cryptographic modules, so you cannot ask the Cipher class or your app to be compliant unless you are implementing a cryptographic module yourself (regardless apparent weaknesses in the code)